# How do you change eclipse blank activity?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-activity

I tried searching and can't find an answer. I want to configure the blankActivity that eclipse provide. It's always have relativeLayout as default and I want it to be LinearLayout. Just a pain having to change that all the time.

Answer (score 3):

You can write your own [templates](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/231329/android/templatedocs/index.html) with the latest ADT. Someone already created some: https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-adt-templates

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to change it by altering the activity_simple.xml.ftl file. It should be in a path like below

```
D:\android-sdk-windows\tools\templates\activities\BlankActivity\root\res\layout
```

I haven't tried this. But its worth a try. Also restart eclipse after any changes is done.